# Outlook rule to identify forwarded email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, forwarding, email-filter, rules

Emails are (auto)forwarded to my inbox. How can I identify such email, not relying on sender, recipient and subject fields (i.e. not using subject = FW:)? Is there a technical way?

Comment: How exactly these emails are being auto-forwarded? By Exchange Server?

Comment: What's your concern about using "subject=FW"?

Comment: @YukiSun Good question. We share an email address and occasionally someone forwards respond to private address. Resulting email has subject FW: and sender = shared address but is not autoforwarded.